# MVC 5 Windows Authentication redirect

Tags: model-view-controller

I created an MVC 5 project and using Windows Authentication.
My problem is whenever an use's action is denied by the action attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Roelabc")], the browser will pop up an login alert with username/passwor.
Now I don't want this pop up, I just want if user is denied then redirect user to an customised page.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class derived from AuthorizeAttribute, will solve my problem.

```
public class WindowsAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "client", filterContext.RouteData.Values[ "client" ] },
                    { "controller", "Home" },
                    { "action", "Contact" },
                    { "ReturnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

And use it like this

```
[WindowsAuthorize(Roles = "User1")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string runDate = "")
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view called unathorized. And in your logon class, just redirect to that view. You can use something like this in logon.cs

```
if (AuthenticateUser())
        {
            if (CheckRulesOfBehavior())
            {
                AuthorizeUser();
                HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Work/Index");
            }
    else
        {
          HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Errors/Unauthorized");
        }
```

Comment: Hi, there is no login function in windows authentication. Thanks all the same. I found the solution by override the the default Authorize attribute. See below post.